# how do i get eclipse to interpret .ejs files as .html?

Tags: eclipse, node.js, ide, express, ejs

i recently started on a node project and two of the modules i'm using is express and EJS. but default i usually use eclipse as my IDE, it works well for java and decent for html and javascript. but one problem i'm having is that for .ejs files i get no markup color coding, or any form of code completion. it's basically just a plain file.

does anyone know how i can get eclipse to interpret .ejs files as .html files? i figure it's pretty similar except for the occasional embed tags. or a recommendation for an IDE more well suited to node.js/html/ejs development.

thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For a specific file, try right-click, *Open With -> Other... -> HTML editor*. You can also set the file association globally under *Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations*.

On a Mac, the global setting is under *Mac Option -> Preferences* and all the same options.

Comment: cool thanks for that! the general steps were correct, i'll add some more details in case anyone else comes across this. after adding it globally Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations, adding  *.ejs as a new file type, then adding HTML as the associated HTML editor, i also had to go to Preferences -> General -> Content Types. Expand Text, then click on HTML, then at the bottom window add *.ejs to the file associations. everything looks good! thanks rlegendi!

Comment: This I already have, but I get warnings all over the place saying Invalid Character used when doing `<%-`

Answer (score 6):

As an addendum to rlegendi's answer, if you'd also like the proper html coloring, you need to go to "Content Types" (right above "Editors" in the Preferences). From here, select *Text -> HTML* and click on "Add..", including .ejs

Answer (score 3):

For me, the best way has been:

Windows > Preferences > General > Content types

In window **Content types** i've selected Text > HTML

and window **File associations** click **Add...** and i've included ***.ejs**

Comment: Ok, i just saw that Andrew Martin says the same. -_-