# Node Ejs module, include not working

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

Im having some trouble including a html snippets into my index.html .
I have tried to follow, the ejs documentation but I just can't seem to make it work.

Directory Structure:

```
project
-public
--assets
---css
---images
---js
--Index
---index.html + index.css and index.js
--someOtherPageFolder
-views
--partials
---partials1.ejs
--index.ejs
--layout.ejs
-server.js
```

This is my server.js (*NEW*):

```
var express  = require("express");
var partials = require("express-partials");
var http     = require('http');
var path     = require('path');
var app      = express();

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.redirect("index");
});

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8888);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

  app.use(partials());
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
      console.log('App listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
    });
```

This is my test.ejs:

```
<h1>This is test!</h1>
```

And this is where I want the html snipp to go:

```
<div id="sb-site">
    <div class="">
        <p>Not test</p>
        <%- include test.html %> 
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Is there also a way for me to do this and use .html instead of .ejs (Im using eclipse and it doesn't support .ejs files)

Comment: Express' [`app.engine()`](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#app.engine) only affects what extensions are recognized when using [`res.render()`](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#res.render). It won't modify anything sent by an `express.static()` middleware.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Is that the sollution for this problem or is it that server.engine is something I dont really need?

Comment: did you try adding a hyphen after the open tag? `<%- include test.html %>`??

Comment: Also, why aren't you using ejs bundled with express? `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')`

Comment: yes, I have tried a hyphen after the open tag and the I have trid to change it to ejs. I just copy pasted the wrong server.js :P thank you

Comment: Could you update it please :D???

Comment: I will update everything now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express 3 breaks ejs partials, use `express-partials` instead.

```
// Include it like so with your other modules
var express       = require("express");
var partials      = require('express-partials');
var server        = express();

// Finally add it into your server conviguration
server.configure(function(){
   server.set('view engine', 'ejs');
   // Include partials middleware into the server
   server.use(partials());
});
```

In your `.ejs` views, enjoy the luxury like so...

```
<%- include ../partials/header %>

<section id="welcome">
  Welcome
</section>

<%- include ../partials/footer %>
```

Also, rather than setting the ejs module to read `.html` just follow this answer to get eclipse to render `.ejs` as `.html`. [how do i get eclipse to interpret .ejs files as .html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035329/how-do-i-get-eclipse-to-interpret-ejs-files-as-html)

As an example, this is how a basic express structure is setup...

```
project
--public
--views
----layout.ejs
----index.ejs
----partials
------partial1.ejs
--server.js
```

server.js would look like...

```
var express  = require('express'),
    partials = require('express-partials'),
    http     = require('http'),
    path     = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.configure(function() {
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3838);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

  // Middleware
  app.use(partials());
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('App listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Your route would look like...

```
server.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("index");
});
```

And finally, your layout.ejs...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%- body %>
  </body>
</html>
```

and index.ejs ...

```
<div id="index">
  <%- include partial1.ejs %>
</div>
```

If you need a reference to the working example, [here it is](https://github.com/sethkrasnianski/express-partials-example)

Comment: thank you! But I still cant seem to make it work ? 
I have done all of the above but when I then go to the site it just downloads the index.ejs file. And I dont think I understand "in your .ejs views..". Do I need a seperate folder for my .ejs files? This is looking much better though :)

Comment: yes, did you add `server.set('views', __dirname + '/views');` in your config? You need to add a directory for your views to serve from.

Comment: I have now added     
    server.set('views', __dirname + '/views'); 
+
    server.use(express.static('public', __dirname + '/public'));
My index.html is in my /public folder. Do I then include .ejs files from the /views folder?

Comment: Yes! layouts and all views go in the views folder, refer to my edit, under "Your router would look like..." to see how to render the view.

Comment: By all views, I mean all .ejs files reside in your views directory

Comment: okay thanks. I have done everyhting you have told me so far, but Im still not able to make it work. I think it may be because I dont understand what I need layout.ejs and partials1.ejs for or what my index is. Is my index and all my future web pages located in the "/views" folder? I can write down how my directory is set up in the original post and update all the code if you want to? btw, it still download the index.ejs file to my downloads folder instead of showing it in the browser when I got to localhost. Thank you for all your help so far! :D

Comment: Not a problem, thank YOU for choosing node.js. The directory structure would help immensely and any updates you've made to your server setup, please add to your original post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50168/discussion-between-seth-and-rockyy)

Answer (score 7):

With include you shoud do like this:

`<%- include ("./partials/footer") %>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the new include syntax:

before: <%- include test.html %>
after: <%- include ('test') %>